# Не меняется позиция при использовании NSNumber в Objective-C (xCode)

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Вот сам код:

```
{
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *number=[formatter numberFromString: LabelSchetBilet.text];
number=[NSNumber numberWithInt:number.intValue-1];
LabelSchetBilet.text=number.stringValue;
if ([LabelSchetBilet.text isEqualToString:@"-1"])
{
    LabelSchetBilet.text = @"0";
}
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

if ([LabelSchetBilet.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
{
    Bilet6.frame = CGRectMake(230, -450, Bilet5.frame.size.width, Bilet6.frame.size.height);
}
}
```

Вот, тут у нас отнимается от LabelSchetBilet -1, и если labelsc.. = 2, то позиция Bilet6 меняется...

Но этого не происходит, позиция не меняется.. Но если сделать в отдельной кнопке

```
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

    if ([LabelSchetBilet.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        Bilet6.frame = CGRectMake(230, -450, Bilet5.frame.size.width, Bilet6.frame.size.height);
    }
```

то все идеально работает... Почему так??

Comment: Суровый вопрос (шутка ;)) Если серьезно, то, что вы имеете в виду под "сделать в отдельной кнопке" и соответственно что значит "не в отдельной"?.. Это разъяснение поможет лучше понять, что именно вы делаете.

Comment: А дебаггер на что?

Comment: Еще две просьбы - пожалуйста отформатируйте свой код (нужно сделать отступ 4 символа, если отступ уже есть - просто сделайте аккуратнее отступы) и что там у вас за функция, от которой в вашем коде остались лишь внешние скобки?

Comment: в отдельной кнопке, это т.е сделать button, и на него поставить только изменение позиции..

Comment: Дебаггер каким путём идёт? Он заходит в изменение позиции?

Comment: Из того, что вы пишите, я не могу к сожалению уловить, что вы делаете и что хотите сделать. В этой ситуации я вижу два варианта: 1) суровый вариант - воспользоваться строгим и верным ответом @Define и заняться внимательно отладкой - все в ваших руках 2) подумать, как написать свой вопрос так, чтобы его поняли (сейчас точно непонятно) - подсказка: четко опишите что значит в отдельной а что не в отдельной - и не только опишите, но приведите два куска кода: работающий первый и неработающий второй, чтобы все смогли увидеть ту разницу из которой возникает неудовлетворительный для вас результат.

Comment: Сори за тупой вопрос, а [UIView commitAnimations]; имеется в коде после [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];?

Comment: http://rghost.ru/47459955

вот пример... Кнопка 1 - меняет позицию, и отнимает число.. Кнопка 2 - просто меняет позицию

Comment: Для вас сделала проект... Откройте, посмотрите

Comment: Спасибо, глянем.

Comment: Ну так что?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Терпение, терпение. У меня кончились комментарии, поэтому отвечаю в ответ.

Я скажу первое, что заметил - у вас в свойствах вашей черной картинки в Xcode стоит галочка Use Autolayout. Уберите ее и все начнет двигаться.

Comment: Если то, что я ответил верно и вам помогло, дайте знать. Я напишу еще несколько строк по поводу того, как лучше делать даже то простое, что вы пытаетесь делать.

Comment: Я лохушка) Спасибо :*

Comment: Все работает, давайте)

Comment: Короче ответ получен - я могу еще кое-чем поделиться, но мне проще это сказать скайпом, так как я второй день подряд не хочу писать длинные разъяснительные тексты. Короче, добавься в скайп (он у меня в профиле). Я не кусаюсь.

Comment: Последний мой комментарий в этом топике: как мы выяснили NSNumber оказался ни в чем не виноват, поэтому предлагаю изменить формулировку вопроса, чтобы она никого не путала здесь на ХК: "Не удается изменить расположение картинки (UIImageView, frame)"

Comment: Ну или там "Не меняется позиция..." но чтобы было UIImageView вместо NSNumber ;)